# Java ResultSet Method to Get Oracle RAW Type

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I have a result set returned by a select query to an Oracle DB. One of the returned rows is of the `RAW` type. Based on what I can tell from the [Database JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/datacc.htm#JJDBC28363), `RAW` maps to Java's `byte[]` type, which indicates that I should use [ResultSet's getBytes() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)). This is the first time that I have used Oracle's `RAW` type, I was wondering if `getBytes()` is indeed the way to go or if another retrieval method (other than `getBytes()`) is a more appropriate choice. I've tried Googling and searching for other SO questions, some of which seem to suggest `getBytes()`, but nothing definitive. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just write some code and try it out?

Comment: I did and it's fine. Just wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: You already have an answer from an authorative source, the documentation. What more do you expect?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I hear what you're saying but I was just hoping to see if there were better ways of doing it. Also, while the source was authoritative, I don't think that the "answer" was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As RAW can only contain 2000 bytes of data (according to [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903)) you can safely retrieve it using `getBytes()`. It's also possible to process with `getBinaryStream()` - but given the comparatively small memory footprint I'd advise againt that.